# Handing dates in Zend_Form - changing to and from date formats

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm working on a Zend Framework (v1.7) application that calls for a few forms that users need to enter dates on.

The user is prompted to enter dates in the **dd/mm/yyyy** format, but the MySQL database wants the dates to be presented in **yyyy-mm-dd** format. Therefore, i'm having to do the following:

*Loading the form*

1. Grab the data from the database
2. Re-format the date fields using Zend_Date into the **dd/mm/yyyy** format

*Saving the form*

1. Validate the date fields using Zend_Validate
2. Check if the date field is present. If so, re-format it into the **yyyy-mm-dd** format. If not, set it to NULL
3. Save to the database

There must be an easier way to do this :-S

Can anyone suggest one?

Cheers,
   Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the reformatting if you use the according sql functions like [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in MySql. The rest looks ok to me.